# differentiate polymorphic association type in views

Tags: ember.js

In my view I'm iterating through a list of messages which is a polymorphic association. I want to render different attributes from my polymorphic model (eg. Comment, Post) based on the polymorphic_type.

How could this be handled in handlebars?

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
 messages: DS.hasMany(App.Message, {polymorphic: true})
});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  user: DS.belongsTo(App.User)
});

App.Post = App.Message.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Comment = App.Message.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Comment: Good point. Don't know why I didn't find this one, read so many. Thanks!